# Overleaf: Picture Formatting

Tags: latex, overleaf

I want to fit my image in the Overleaf but the output result is not as expected.
The overleaf code i used is as:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{Fig2.png}
    \label{Fig1}
   
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Fig_3.png}
    \label{Fig2}
   
\end{figure}
```

However my image is coming on top of the text of the other sections, any solutions are appreciated.
Note: The Image needs the whole page width to be accommodated

Answer (score -1):

Try `\pagebreak` before and/or after images.
The next option is to replace `[htb]` with `[!h]`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).